# VBA Custom Event Not Found when Raised in UserForm

Tags: events, vba, userform

I was following [this MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140931%28v=office.10%29.aspx) on creating custom events.  I feel like I understand the process now, but I cannot figure out why I am getting a `Compile Error: Event Not Found` for `RaiseEvent ItemAdded`.  The weird thing is, the ItemAdded event is recognized by the IDE (I can type it in all lowercase and it is then automatically formatted properly), so I *know* that it is recognized by VB.

### DataComboBox Class Module Code:

```
Public Event ItemAdded(sItem As String, fCancel As Boolean)

Private pComboBox As Control

Public Property Set oComboBox(cControl As Control)
    Set pComboBox = cControl
End Property

Public Property Get oComboBox() As Control
    oComboBox = pComboBox
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

End Sub
```

The UserForm contains two controls - a CommandButton named btnAdd and a ComboBox named cboData.

### UserForm Code:

```
Private WithEvents mdcbCombo As DataComboBox

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mdcbCombo = New DataComboBox
    Set mdcbCombo.oComboBox = Me.cboData
End Sub

Private Sub mdcbCombo_ItemAdded(sItem As String, fCancel As Boolean)
    Dim iItem As Long
    If LenB(sItem) = 0 Then
        fCancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For iItem = 1 To Me.cboData.ListCount
        If Me.cboData.List(iItem) = sItem Then
            fCancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next iItem
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim sItem As String
    sItem = Me.cboData.Text
    AddDataItem sItem
End Sub

Private Sub AddDataItem(sItem As String)
    Dim fCancel As Boolean
    fCancel = False
    
    RaiseEvent ItemAdded(sItem, fCancel)
    
    If Not fCancel Then Me.cboData.AddItem (sItem)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot raise an event outside the classes file level.

Add a routine like this inside "DataComboBox1" to allow you to raise the event externally.

```
Public Sub OnItemAdded(sItem As String, fCancel As Boolean)
    RaiseEvent ItemAdded(sItem, fCancel)
End Sub
```

Then call the OnItemAdded with the current object.

Example...

```
Private WithEvents mdcbCombo As DataComboBox
...
mdcbCombo.OnItemAdded(sItem, fCancel)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that the function was a member of the class and not of the userform.  The `Me.ComboBox.Text` threw me off.